# What are the LatLngBounds for India?

Tags: android, google-maps, google-places-api, latitude-longitude

I am using the AutoComplete Places Widget in my android application. I want set the bounds to only India. But I do not know the LatLngBounds for India. Anyone have any idea about the co-ordinates?

Comment: Stackoverflow is not a site for these types of questions. You should google coordinates instead of asking them here.

Comment: I got the answer here so. Thanks for your help anyway :)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use this..

```
private static final LatLngBounds BOUNDS_INDIA = new LatLngBounds(new LatLng(23.63936, 68.14712), new LatLng(28.20453, 97.34466));
```

Comment: where to add this BOUND_INDIA

Comment: What are the LatLngBounds for Bangladesh??

Answer (score 9):

If you want to cover entire India (Though it will also cover some parts of China, Pakistan and Bangladesh), Use below bounds:-

```
public static final LatLngBounds BOUNDS_INDIA = new LatLngBounds(new LatLng(7.798000, 68.14712), new LatLng(37.090000, 97.34466));
```

As per google documentation:-

```
public LatLngBounds (LatLng southwest, LatLng northeast)

Creates a new bounds based on a southwest and a northeast corner.

The bounds conceptually includes all points where:

1. the latitude is in the range [northeast.latitude, southwest.latitude];
2. the longitude is in the range [southwest.longtitude, northeast.longitude] if southwest.longtitude ≤ northeast.longitude;
```

To find latitude and longitude of any place 
use:- http://www.findlatitudeandlongitude.com/

Answer (score 4):

You can get the bounds of any country using this API

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?key=YOUR_API_KEY&address=india

place your key inplace of YOUR_API_KEY , in address place the country

You will get response similar to this

```
  {
   "results" : [
      {
         "address_components" : [
            {
               "long_name" : "India",
               "short_name" : "IN",
               "types" : [ "country", "political" ]
            }
         ],
         "formatted_address" : "India",
         "geometry" : {
            "bounds" : {
               "northeast" : {
                  "lat" : 35.513327,
                  "lng" : 97.39535869999999
               },
               "southwest" : {
                  "lat" : 6.4626999,
                  "lng" : 68.1097
               }
            },
            "location" : {
               "lat" : 20.593684,
               "lng" : 78.96288
            },
            "location_type" : "APPROXIMATE",
            "viewport" : {
               "northeast" : {
                  "lat" : 35.513327,
                  "lng" : 97.39535869999999
               },
               "southwest" : {
                  "lat" : 6.4626999,
                  "lng" : 68.1097
               }
            }
         },
         "place_id" : "ChIJkbeSa_BfYzARphNChaFPjNc",
         "types" : [ "country", "political" ]
      }
   ],
   "status" : "OK"
}
```

in geometry bounds you get sountwest and northeast bounds just use them

```
private static final LatLngBounds BOUNDS_INDIA = new LatLngBounds(
       new LatLng(6.4626999, 68.1097),
       new LatLng(35.513327, 97.39535869999999)
     );
```

Answer (score 1):

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/autocomplete/json?input=Kolka&country=IN&key=YOUR_API_KEY

Create a server key from google console
https://console.developers.google.com/apis/credentials

[image]